# Change the css style of multiple div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have e.x 3 boxes, the red one should have at start a bigger size then the others (through css). Now, when I click on the green or yellow box the red gets smaller size same as green or yellow had before clicking. And the clicked one gets the CSS Style (size) of the red one. I want to make it with JQuery but don't know how?

```css
.r1, .r2, .r3{
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 40px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .r1{
        background-color: red;
        position: inherit;
            transform: scaleY(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);
            transform-origin: center;
            border: 2px solid #15dc6e;
    }
    .r2{
        background-color: green;
    }
    .r3{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="r1"></div>
  <div class="r2"></div>
  <div class="r3"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwx3ukra/16/

Comment: Extract the css part that makes the div bigger into its own class.  On clicking of a div, put the class on it and remove it from the others.

Comment: Yes i forgot that, sry.. , I know in jquery there is addClass and removeClass but I dont know how to use them correct with onclick and especially in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready( () => {
 $('.content div').click( e => {
   // Remove zoom class from all elements
   $('.content div').removeClass('big');
    // Only apply to the clicked element
   $(e.target).addClass('big');
  });
})
```

```css
.r1,
.r2,
.r3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.r1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.r2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.r3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.big {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border: 2px solid #15dc6e;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="r1 big"></div>
  <div class="r2"></div>
  <div class="r3"></div>
</div>
```

[**Working JSFiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwx3ukra/45/)

You can achieve a smooth transition using pure CSS:

```
.r1,
.r2,
.r3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.big {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border: 2px solid #15dc6e;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

The `transition` property will automatically transition from one rule to another. In this example, it transitions from `transform: scale(1)` to `transform: scale(1.2)`.

Comment: @codeCad Thank you, please accept as the correct answer if this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/samandalso/pen/qKrLLM

```
$(function() {
    $('.content div').on('click', function(){
      $('.content div').not($(this)).removeClass('scaled');
      $(this).toggleClass('scaled');
    });
});
```